# How to Find which response belongs to which request in Async api calling using URLSession

Tags: swift, asynchronous, request, response, nsurlsession

I'm using `URLSession` to get the response from the `API's` in my iPhone app. In my case, I'm hitting around 10 requests of a same api at a time using Asynchronous API calling and I'm getting the response for all the requests. Now from those responses how can I find which response belongs to which request? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Would you like to include the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many ways to achieve this.

1 - Basically, if you call your client function with an identifier, you will be able to retrieve it in your completion block:

```
func call(with identifier: String, at url: URL) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(url: url) { (_, _, _) in
        print(identifier)
    }.resume()
}
```

2 - You can also use the taskIdentifier of an `URLSessionDataTask`. But to do this, you will need to use the delegate of your custom `URLSession`:

```
self.session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
                          delegate: self,
                          delegateQueue: nil)
```

then you will not use a completion block but the delegate function instead:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive response: URLResponse, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.ResponseDisposition) -> Void) {
    print(dataTask.taskIdentifier)
}
```

(of course you need to know which task identifier has been set for which `URLSessionDataTask`)

3 - If you need to access your identifier from your completion block, you can write a function which will happened it in the list of the parameter of the default completion block:

```
func dataTask(session: URLSession,
              url: URL,
              identifier: String,
              completionBlock: @escaping (String, Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask {
    return session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        completionBlock(identifier, data, response, error)
    }
}
```

4 - If you need to have a custom identifier in a `URLSessionDataTask` object, you can add it using extension and associated object:

```
extension URLSessionDataTask {
    var identifier: String? {
        get {
            let identifier = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &kIdentiferId)
            if let id = identifier as? String {
                return id
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &kIdentiferId, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        }
    }
}

private var kIdentiferId: Int8 = 100
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
let task = session.dataTask(url: url)
task.identifier = "hello"
```